# Same git repository on multiple private network

Tags: git, multiple-repositories, private-network

We have two private networks and one of them has local git repository. Only one computer can connect each networks. Other developers cannot connect each networks, developer should develop in their networks. We want to make two git repository for each networks, we must sync these git repositories daily using computer that connects these networks. How can we setup two git repositories and sync it daily?

Comment: Sounds like a truly horrible idea.

Comment: What should happen when the history splits, for example when both repositories get something pushed, and merging those things gives merge conflicts

Comment: I am asking for is there  a way for one history, one git repository but two different network. Can I sync these repos changing network cables.

Comment: Our customer is working on private network and we are working on another private network which is our development environment. We want to continue develelopment in customer side but we also want to merge these changes with our development environment so we need something like this.